# Programmatically emulate the selection in UITableViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Sorry for the question without any line of code. I need advice how to proceed, if at possible that I want.

In Swift language.

Let us assume there is an app with two controllers - `UITableViewController` with embedded `NavigationController`, as the main. When you select a row in the table, opens `UIViewController`, which displays detailed information about the selected value.

Is it possible to do otherwise? When the application start, programmatically emulate the selection of the first row in the table and immediately display `UIViewController` with detailed information about the selected value. And from this controller possible to return to `UITableViewController` via the `NavigationController`.

Once again I apologize and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes you can do this in swift.Just load your `tableViewController` as usual.You just have to call

In Swift

```
    let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0);  //slecting 0th row with 0th section
    self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None);
```

The `selectRowAtIndexPath` function will not trigger delegate methods like `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` so you have to manually trigger this delegate method

```
   self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect); //Manually trigger the row to select
```

Or  If you are pushing `ViewControllers` with segue you have to trigger `performSegueWithIdentifier`

```
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender: self);
```

Now you can push viewController in `didSelectRowAtIndexpath`.To select  the first row in first section or execute whaterver you have written in  `didSelectRowAtIndexpath:` of `tableView`

As For your case just push the `viewController` on select at 0th index with `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        self.navigationController.pushViewController(yourViewControllerToPush, animated: YES);
    }
    //handle other index or whatever according to your conditions
}
```

It will show the view controller pushed and if you do not want to animate view controller just pass `NO` to `pushViewController` method.

On pressing `Back` button you will back to your `viewController`

In your case just write this in your `viewDidAppear`

```
if firstStart {
    firstStart = false
    let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showForecastSelectedCity", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: In my viewDidAppear: `........ if firstStart {
            firstStart = false
            let rowToSelect:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
            self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(rowToSelect, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
            self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect)
        }`  my **didSelectRowAtIndexPath**:   `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showForecastSelectedCity", sender: self)
    }`

Comment: Error: `[_TtC12WeatherTest229FavWeatherTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f7fea81d880
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_TtC12WeatherTest229FavWeatherTableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent`  What is wrong?

Comment: As you are not implementing `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you do not need to call `self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: rowToSelect)`.

Answer (score 9):

You can also do this simply by accessing the tableView delegate to force `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to fire.

Programatically select a row to work with:

```
self.tableView.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top)
```

Programatically selecting row does not fire the "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" function so we must manually force the firing as per below:

```
self.tableView.delegate!.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath!)
```

Objective-C:

```
[self.tableView.delegate tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:path];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It took a little modifying for Swift 4:
`tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.top)` and `tableView.delegate!.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)`

Comment: Straight to the point and much cleaner than the selected answer. Works very nicely.