# Swift didDeselectRowAtIndexPath not working on preset cell

Tags: swift

I have a table I use that shows timezone options. I use a checkmark to show which one is currently selected. When the table is created I checkmark the cell that is saved as the users timezone.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellData")

        switch indexPath.row {
            case 0: cell.textLabel?.text = "Eastern"
            case 1: cell.textLabel?.text = "Central"
            case 2: cell.textLabel?.text = "Mountain"
            case 3: cell.textLabel?.text = "Mountain (No DST)"
            case 4: cell.textLabel?.text = "Pacific"
            default: cell.textLabel?.text = ""
        }

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        if(cell.textLabel?.text == keychain.get("timezone")) {

            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

        }

        return cell
    }
```

Then I use these functions to change the checkmark when a user chooses a new timezone.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

}
```

However, when I preset the checkmark it is not removed when I choose a new timezone. It will only work if I first select it and then choose a new one. Is there a reason the original cell is not affected on deselect?

Comment: My guess is that checking `accessoryType` is just a "mental selection" defined by you and it has nothing to do with the real selection. You might need to select a row by something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787098/programmatically-emulate-the-selection-in-uitableviewcontroller-in-swift , only then `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` will work for you.

Comment: @JoeHuang when I use the code from that question I am getting an error that it is nil in didSelect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your original cell isn't being deselected is that it's not selected in the first place. Enabling the checkmark accessory doesn't select the cell.

It's a bit of a pain to set up, but one way you could get this working is by storing a reference to the cell that needs to be selected, and when the view is going to appear, select it manually. Then, deselections will work.

Add a class variable to remember the cell that should be selected

`var initiallySelectedPath: NSIndexPath?`

Set the variable in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (personally, I'd do this setting elsewhere in the class due to how the actual cell selection is going to be performed, but this is good enough to demonstrate *a* solution.

```
...
if (cell.textLabel?.text == keychain.get("timezone")) {
  cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
  initiallySelectedPath = indexPath
}
...
```

Then, in your `viewWillAppear`

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  if let indexPath = initiallySelectedPath {
    // I force unwrap (sorry!) my tableView, you'll need to change this to however you reference yours
    tableView!.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
  }
}
```

Now your original cell should deselect with the first tap on a different cell.

Comment: I didn't need to store it, I just used your line of code from view will appear inside the original table view method to make the cell selected.